# checking whether or not any checkbox input is checked from array of input

Tags: javascript

I have a node list of chechbox inputs

```
const searchSizeSelectionInputs = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".sizeHolderFilter > input")
```

I have written a function to check whether or not any checkbox is checked or not, the function is

```
const activationChecker = ()=>{
  if (
    availabilityInStoreOptions[0].classList.contains("activeSortOptionSP") ||
    availabilityInStoreOptions[1].classList.contains("activeSortOptionSP")
  ) {
    isAvailabilityInStorActive = true;
  }
  if(  !availabilityInStoreOptions[0].classList.contains("activeSortOptionSP") &&
    !availabilityInStoreOptions[1].classList.contains("activeSortOptionSP")) {
    isAvailabilityInStorActive = false;
  }
  searchSizeSelectionInputs.forEach(input => {
    if (input.checked) {
      isSizeInputChecked = true;
    } else {
      let isSizeInputChecked = false;
    }
  });
  searchColorSelectionInputs.forEach(input => {
    if (input.checked) {
      isColorInputChecked = true;
    } else {
      let isColorInputChecked = false;
    }
  });

};
```

the thing is, when I check the result of isSizeInputChecked or isColorInputChecked it gives me faulty answers, for example when I check the checkbox it gives me true and when I uncheck the checkbox it still gives me true, I tested the same code on one single object and it works beautifully,I believe I do have a problem on doing this on a node list. This must be the wrong way:

```
searchSizeSelectionInputs.forEach(input => {
    if (input.checked) {
      isSizeInputChecked = true;
    } else {
      let isSizeInputChecked = false;
    }
```

How can I check if any checkbox is checked or not any of them is checked?

Comment: dude, I tried to make the question as clear as I could,sorry anyway.

Comment: why is there not a `let` on the `if (input.checked) { isSizeInputChecked = true;...` test, is it a global variable while in the other case it is a local variable? it's really not clear

Comment: no I declared beforehand before reassigning it.

Comment: this is not the point,  a local var doesn't not reassign a global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getCheckedData() {
  let atleastOneChecked=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox'))
    .some(
      function(inputCheckbox) {
        return inputCheckbox.checked;
    }
 
);
let allChecked=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox'))
    .every(
      function(inputCheckbox) {
        return inputCheckbox.checked;
    }
 
);
console.log('atleastOneChecked',atleastOneChecked);
console.log('allChekecked',allChecked);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox'>
<input type="checkbox" class='checkbox'>

<button onclick="getCheckedData()">Get checked data</button>
```

The **document.querySelectorAll** returns a NodeList and it is not an array. We have to convert node list into an array using **Array.from** and use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function from Array to get atleast one of the element is checked or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude.have a beautiful day or night.